# Need to Implement Custom Dimensions through Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have created virtual pageview tag successfully for " New Registrations" via Google Tag manager.

Now, I want to add two custom dimensions using same Tag i.e. Customer ID and UserRole.

Actually, I am not sure where to add the code to get dynamic values for CustomerID and UserRole. Can you guide me to complete this?

Answer (score 0):

Custom dimensions are configured either in the Google Analytics settings variable (if you use this), or in the tag via the "More Settings" >> "Custom Dimensions" settings or both.

If you use a settings variable and want to add extra dimensions to a specific tag you need to tick the "Enable override settings" checkbox.

In the settings you enter in the first field the numeric index of the dimensions (you can look this up in the property settings of your GA account where you have created the dimensions), the second field takes the variable with a value (or a simple string if it's not a dynamic value).

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my question. I have taken few steps which are:

Created new Custom dimensions in GA. You can see here: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2ywctp2&s=9

Created 'Custom Variables" in GTM against each "Custom dimension". And added "Index value" and "Dimension value" into a GTM tag. You can see here: http://tinypic.com/r/f0sncz/9

Comment: FYI: I have added following data layer for registration virtual page view. 
window.dataLayer.push({ 'event' : 'virtualPageview', 'virtualPageURL' : '/virtual/registration-complete', 'VirtualPageTitle' : 'Registration Complete'});

Do I need to push separate data layer for custom dimensions? Do I need to add anything under trigger?

Please advice!!

Comment: Can Anyone please help me on this?